# Validate (Australian) Phone Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I need to validate Australian phone numbers (e.g. `02[3-9]\d{7}` or `07[3-9]\d{7}`  or `04[\d]{8}`) in JavaScript.

**Requirements:**

- must be 10 digits
- no commas
- no dashes
- no + in front
- must begin with 0

At the moment I can validate required fields and email address but I want to add phone number validation.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
 var x=document.forms["form3"]["name"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="") {
   alert("Name must be filled out");
   return false;
 }
 var s=document.forms["form3"]["phone"].value;
 if (s==null || s=="") {
   alert("Please Enter your Phone or Mobile Number - Preferably Phone Number");
   return false;
 }
 var s=document.forms["form3"]["email"].value;
 if (s==null || s=="") {
   alert("Please Enter a valid email address");
   return false;
 }
 var k=document.forms["form3"]["email"].value;
 var atpos=k.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=k.lastIndexOf(".");
 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=k.length) {
   alert("Email Address is Not Valid. Please provide your correct email address.");
   return false;
 }
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>

<form action="/thank-you.php" name="form3" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
Your name* <input type="text" name="name" />    
Phone number* <input type="text" name="phone" />
Email* <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="sumbit" name="submit" class="button" onclick="javascript:return validateMyForm();" /><input type="reset" value="Reset" class="resetbutton" />
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Can someone help out?

Comment: Note that YOU CAN'T RELY on client data (not even client-side validated data)

Comment: @kaᵠ It is better to have client side validation as well as server side validating because if client side validation fails, it just won't going to submit which might save some HTTP request.

Comment: @EnglishMaster And improve user experience also as the (genuine) user would prefer to know any mistakes right there and then, and not after the site has taken time to process the page and bring back the results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a regex that I would recomment

```
var pattern = /^0[0-8]\d{8}$/g;
```

So input must start with 0, and followed by a digit and it must be one between 0-8. Then it must have 8 more digit numbers.

Valid phone number examples:

0010293999  (ok)

0110293999  (ok)

0210293999  (ok)

0910293999  (nope)

//Implementation

```
 ........
 var phoneNumber =document.forms["form3"]["phone"].value;
 var phonePattern = /^0[0-8]\d{8}$/g;
 //phone number is not valid. Please notice that you don't need to check if it's empty or null since Regex checks it for you anyways
 if (!phoneNumber.test(phonePattern))
   {
   alert("Please Enter your Phone or Mobile Number - Preferably Phone Number");
   return false;
   }
 ..........
```

---- Edit

```
........
     var phoneNumber =document.forms["form3"]["phone"].value;
     var phonePattern = /^0[0-8]\d{8}$/g;
     //phone number is not valid. Please notice that you don't need to check if it's empty or null since Regex checks it for you anyways
     if (!phonePattern.test(phoneNumber))
       {
       alert("Please Enter your Phone or Mobile Number - Preferably Phone Number");
       return false;
       }
     ..........
```

Comment: Nah didn't work. just added your code but it sends the web message without validating all fields.

Comment: I thought you are asking about regex for phonenumber?

Comment: I am sorry, there was a small error from the example code. it must be !phonePattern.test(phoneNumber) instead of !phoneNumber.test(phonePattern)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: Basically test is not a function of a String =/

Comment: All good now. Thanks heaps. sorry I am not able to vote you up as I don't have 15 reputation yet. I'll def do it in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Some of the provided patterns would not match Australian phone numbers, as per OP question. Numbers starting 05, for instance, would not be valid for Australia, for instance. http://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/facts-and-figures/telephone-country-and-area-codes

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Paul Ferrett](http://paulferrett.com/2010/validate-australian-phone-numbers-in-php/) for this (php not js, but the regex should translate):

```
<?php
function validate_phone($number) {
  $number = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $number);
  return preg_match('/^(0(2|3|4|7|8))?\d{8}$/', $number)
    || preg_match('/^1(3|8)00\d{6}$/', $number)
    || preg_match('/^13\d{4}$/', $number);
}
```

NB: "MIT License"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more robust Australian phone regex. Courtesy of [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990179/regex-for-australian-phone-number-validation) question.

```js
let phonePattern = /^(?:\+?(61))? ?(?:\((?=.*\)))?(0?[2-57-8])\)? ?(\d\d(?:[- ](?=\d{3})|(?!\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]))\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]?\d{3})$/
```

##### Testing:

```js
0412123123      TRUE
0491579999      TRUE
0491572983      TRUE
0712122123      TRUE
0212122123      TRUE
0000000000      FALSE
5555551234      FALSE
04121231231     FALSE
041212312       FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Javascript [RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) and RegExp [`test()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) method.

```
var patt = /04[\d]{8}/g; // Shorthand for RegExp object

var phoneNumber1 = '0412345678';
var result1 = patt.test(phoneNumber1); // result1 is true

var phoneNumber2 = 'abc';
var result2 = patt.test(phoneNumber2); // result2 is false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the required pattern.

I've never used it before but it looks like this:

```
<input type="text" 
  id="phoneNumber"
  title="Phone numbers must be 10 digits and start with 0." 
  required pattern="0[::digit::]{10}"
/>

// It's late, no idea if that's a valid regex or if works with POSIX.
```

See this html5rocks article for more info:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-validation

Comment: thanks. This one works like a charm. The problem is the error message for phone field is different from other JavaScript error messages...

Comment: Nah on second thought, this one doesn't work when filling the form through the IE browsers.

Comment: There's nothing special about `required pattern=`. That's just two attributes, `pattern=`, and `required`.