# Minimum length Regex

Tags: regex

I need help enforcing a correct Australian phone number.  This is what I have so far.  How can I make this require the user to start the number with either '02,04,03,07 or 08 and it Must be 10 characters long?

```
^\({0,1}((0|\+61)(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\){0,1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$
```

Comment: so you don't want the number to start with `+61` or `(`

Comment: Please explain why your question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595819/validate-australian-10-digit-phone-number-to-begin-with-0-javascript

Comment: Correct.  not +61. just 07 blah or 0427 blah.  The regex is good, it does however let me enter '32090000' rather than enforce '0732090000' as 10 characters and start with 02,03,04,07 or 08).

Comment: did you want it to be exactly 10 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allows exactly 10 characters then remove the unwanted `(`, `-`, `+61` from your regex,

```
^((0)(2|4|3|7|8))[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aP7aD5/2)