# Regex for Australian phone number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I tried below regex for phone numbers validation but did not work properly,

```
^([+61|0](2|4|3|7|8|)){0,2}([ 0-9]|[(]){2,3}([)]|[0-9]){6}([ ])[0-9]{7,20}$
```

Here are examples I expect to pass validation

```
+61(02)89876544
+61 2 8986 6544
02 8986 6544
+61289876544
0414 570776 
0414570776
0414 570 776
+61 414 570776
+61 (0)414 570776
```

below characters also be accepted.
()-+ space

Comment: Aren't `+61(02)89876544` and `+61 (0)414 570776` invalid? Aren't you supposed to drop the `0` from the area code if `+61` is included.

Answer (score 39):

That's quite the phone number structure. The easiest solution is to ask the user to input in a particular format or have the the form automatically format it. If you must use a regex, this is what I came up with:

```
^(?:\+?(61))? ?(?:\((?=.*\)))?(0?[2-57-8])\)? ?(\d\d(?:[- ](?=\d{3})|(?!\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]))\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]?\d{3})$
```

Capture groups:

1. Country Code (optional)
2. Area/Provider Code (optional)
3. The Phone Number

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dkFASs/6

This was what I used to nail down the format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia

When tackling a larger regex like this, I find the esiest way is to stick your test cases into a tool like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and then go capture group by capture group (naming them if you can) until you get to the end. As soon as one group doesn't match, change what you already have until it does.

**Edit 2019:** Since this question still gets attention occasionally, I wanted to note that it might be better to use a validation library if possible. My suggestion would be [Google's i18n library for phone numbers](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). It's much more robust than a regex could ever be.

Comment: looks good, i have to place character limit also min 7 max 20

Comment: What do you mean? This regex will match exactly 8 digits with optional area code (optional zero followed by 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 7, or 8) and optional country code (optional + then 64). If the regex is any longer it's due to either the spaces or dashes inside or more likely, trailing whitespace at the end. Edit: I hope you don't mean the regex length has to be less than 20 characters...

Comment: Phone number length should be 7 to 20 and pattern errors are showing javascript mode in the https://regex101.com

Comment: @KRR I've updated it to use the JavaScript engine (I should have checked which one earlier) As well as including the longest possible match in the list of test inputs (it's 19 characters).

Comment: @KRR, this answer seems to be getting some attention every so often. If it answered your question, could you please mark it as the accepted answer, or if it doesn't, please elaborate on your question so that I can answer it better. (or if you think a different answer is better, please mark that one as accepted)

Comment: The only issue here is that the user may deviate from the format specified. It's necessary to couple a regex like this with string length validation as well, ensuring length is 10. Someone entering `041 23 456 78` would break the validation

Comment: @JustinMitchell Sure but (imo) the question is about validating if it's in a format that is standard in Australia, not validating that it's a 10-digit number. If a user is putting random spaces in between digits, that doesn't fit the standard format.

Comment: For anyone else trying to use this for HTML pattern validation, I had to escape the hyphen in the character classes: `[\- ]`

Answer (score 9):

I up-voted @3ocene's response. But later found didn't quite match my case.

Here's my test case (non exhaustive):

```
+(61) 455 562 400
+61-455-562-400
+61 455 562 400
+(61)-455-562-400
+(61) 455 562 400
(02) 4371 3164
(02) 4371-3164
02 80268989
03 80268989
04 80268989
05 80268989
433245898
433 245 898
433-245-898
4555-62400
123456
08 54 587 456
```

123456 is negative..

This is what I built, so it it helps someone here it is:

```
^(\+?\(61\)|\(\+?61\)|\+?61|\(0[1-9]\)|0[1-9])?( ?-?[0-9]){7,9}$
```

Here's the Regexer link:

https://regex101.com/r/eiufOH/2

Answer (score 4):

I would first remove all whitespace from the phone number as more patterns will mean more complex regex, then apply the following:

```
(?:\+?61)?(?:\(0\)[23478]|\(?0?[23478]\)?)\d{8}
```

As far as I can tell it works.

Will write explanation shortly

Answer (score 2):

Modified 3ocene to include 13, 180, 19, 1300, 1800, 1900

13 xxxx and 1300 xxx xxx – "Local Rate" calls, except for VoIP and mobile phone users

180 xxxx and 1800 xxx xxx – FreeCall

19 xxxx and 19xx xxxx – Premium SMS

```
^(?=.*)((?:\+61) ?(?:\((?=.*\)))?([2-47-8])\)?|(?:\((?=.*\)))?([0-1][2-47-8])\)?) ?-?(?=.*)((\d{1} ?-?\d{3}$)|(00 ?-?\d{4} ?-?\d{4}$)|( ?-?\d{4} ?-?\d{4}$)|(\d{2} ?-?\d{3} ?-?\d{3}$))
```

https://regex101.com/r/dqsaHM/3

Also found this link that can help edit Regex using a flow diagram hope it help

https://ihateregex.io/expr/phone/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
\b([\+-]?\d{2}|\d{4})\s*\(?\d+\)?\s*(?:\d+\s*)+\b
```